# "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Response Header send twice via IIS

Tags: http, iis, cors, same-origin-policy

I am using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for enabling CORS on my site and have the following part added to my site web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**I have used the IIS GUI to change this setting!**

**There are no double entries in the web.config!**

But as soon as I load the page I see following:

[image]

My site is in the only node in the `Sites` folder and my server itself has no custom headers attached to it.

**But why am I getting this doubled response header?**

Comment: Did you use the GUI to change the web.config or did you do it manually?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup I have changed my question. Please see above ;)

Comment: Have you checked the actual config file to confirm there is no double entry?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup I have already checked the config file for double entries and found none... That is why I am confused a bit